# How to change color of a single item in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with setting color from resources for an item in `RecyclerView`.
I've tried this two methods but none works. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
holder.alert.setTextColor(R.color.alertGreen);
holder.alert.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.alertGreen));
```

Comment: post your item xmll here and adapter class

Comment: `setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#54D66A"));`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `ContextCompat` to get color.

```
holder.alert.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.alertGreen));
```

Answer (score 3):

To update the color for the Single item you can follow below technique,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

// Green color to set to specific item in the view [By referencing the position you need to handle the view]
int color1 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.alertGreen));

// Red color to set to remaining Views
int color2 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.alertRed));

     if (position == 1) {
       holder.alert.setTextColor(color1);
     } else {
       holder.alert.setTextColor(color2);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ContextCompact` instead of `getResources()` because this method is `deprecated`.

```
holder.alert.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 1):

In `onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)` method you can change the current element color:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.alert.setTextColor(R.color.alertGreen);
    holder.alert.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.alertGreen);
}
```

And use `ContextCompat` to get the color:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.alertGreen));
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative of using ContextCompat is this:

```
holder.alert.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.alertGreen));
```